# running Remote Desktop Gateway and Exchange server roles against one IP?

Tags: exchange-2010, rdp

I'm interested in running Exchange server roles and RDP (Remote Desktop Gateway) on the same internet facing system.

If anyone has any tricks or tips for getting this working, similar to in SBS11, with one IP address and one SSL SAN/UCC certificate, let me know.

Comment: I may have partially found the answer through google:

Here is a similar setup. 

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/1da9cd90-80f4-4087-9edf-2d9cfa1d312f/